# Data on Route not reloading / refetching from API

Tags: ember.js

Say I have `index` and `edit` routes.
From `index`, I selected item and redirected to `edit` route.
Then when I change data on form field on `edit` route and click the back arrow on my browser, the changes made reflected on `index` which should not because save button was not clicked.

But when `index` route is refreshed the changes made don't reflect which is right. Now how could the `index` route reload the data without refreshing the page.

Comment: I guess you are using [Ember Data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/) isn't it?

Comment: Can you also please specify the ember-cli version you are using. Thank you

Comment: @Mikelemuel `"ember-cli": "^1.13.13"`

Answer (score 3):

This is probably happening because in the edit route you are updating the data model object, so that change will persist in the ember-data model. You can probably see in the ember inspector that when you make changes in your form, the ember-data object in the inspector table turns blue.

There are a couple of ways you can go about this, one would be to use [rollbackAttributes](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.9/classes/DS.Model/methods/rollbackAttributes?anchor=rollbackAttributes) method of the model in the willTransition hook of the edit route, and remove all unsaved changes to the model from ember-data in that way.

You could also use an addon like [ember-changeset](https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset) so you don't make changes directly to the ember-data model with your form until you actually click the save button.